# Magento 2 - Random lines of whitespace being added to top of all html output source code

Tags: magento2

I've been maintaining a Magento 2 website for some time now for the company I work for. The current problem is that all output web pages seem to have one or two random lines of whitespace at the top of each file. See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWK4E.png).

I can't for the life of me find the route cause. It doesn't seem to be the Apache server, as other projects are fine. Index.php and root.phtml don't seem to add any whitespace before the doctype declaration.

All I can tell you is that this doesn't seem to happen on our production server, only local;y and on our test / staging servers.

Any help with figuring out where Magento is adding whitespace from would be greatly appreciated! Apologies for the vague / noob question, am new.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore me, there was a blank line of whitespace at the top of one of my registration.php module files.